# javascript random images script

Tags: javascript, random

I have an online store and I would like to make some improvements. I want to create a script which inserts me on every product page some random images of another products. But these images have to be linked with the description of that product and with the price. So far I got this :

```js
function random_imglink(){
  var myimages=new Array()
  myimages[1]="imagepath1"
  myimages[2]="imagepath2"
  myimages[3]="imagepath3"
  ..............
  ..............

  var imagelinks=new Array()
  imagelinks[1]="link1"
  imagelinks[2]="link2"
  imagelinks[3]="link3"
  ................
  ................
  
  var Quotation=new Array()
  Quotation[1]="<h1>image 1</h1>"
  Quotation[2]="<h1>image 2</h1>"
  Quotation[3]="<h1>image 3</h1>"
  .............
  .............

  var price=new Array()
  price[1]="price1"
  price[2]="price2"
  price[3]="price3"
  ............
  .............
  
  var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)  
  if (ry==0)
     ry=1
   document.write('<a href='+'"'+imagelinks[ry]+'"'+'><img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0> '+Quotation[ry]+' '+price[ry]+'</a>')
     
}   

  random_imglink()
```

The problem is that I want more than just one image which gets randomising. I want 4 images to do that at every refresh...
For example,if I create a table with one row and 4 columns and I copy the code above in every cell the script is working well. But I'm sure there is a beautiful solution.

I hope you people was able to understand me.Sorry for my english !

Comment: Code snippet are just for client side code (html, css and some javascript). Besides, the js code runs only if you call it from a html page, so you should fix it to see some results

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery/AJAX? You can use them to easily accomplish this task and have it populate your "random image" area with the images, desc, price, etc... by having it feed from your database. You can even have it randomly change the images every so often, even if you don't refresh the page. This way the customer has time to see it, and if they're still on the page for awhile, it'll switch up so they can be exposed to even further products.

Comment: I would do that in PHP, with or without AJAX.

Comment: Agreed. AJAX will help make it easier and smooth it out, but PHP is what I personally like to access and deal with my databases. Some prefer ASP, which is fine, but I've no experience with that one.

Comment: Btw, I would recommend using literals to create your arrays, rather than using the `new Array()` means of doing it. Some browsers can be funky, and using literals will give you a more consistent result. As well, it'll do the exact same thing you're doing. Another note, since arrays start with 0, it's better to start there instead of leaving a hole in your array. Not that you can't make it work, but it's typically better practice and can help you from accidentally creating issues when you do other things with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop for it.

html:

```
 <div id="productExposure"></div>
```

In your function (JS/jQuery):

```
while(i=0; i < 3; i++}
{
 var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)  
  if (ry==0)
     ry=1
  $("#productExposure").prepend('<a href='+'"'+imagelinks[ry]+'"'+'><img    src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0> '+Quotation[ry]+' '+price[ry]+'</a>') 
}
```

I haven't tested that, but it should accomplish what you're asking. Instead of having to insert your script into each cell of a table, if you use a loop it'll generate it for all 3. Since it's not hardcoded into your html, every refresh it'll recreate them and it'll be random. However, I would recommend you store the previous value, and then check it in each loop to make sure you're not getting duplicates in the same refresh.

Comment: If you're using PHP (or similar) to handle your database, you can remove most of your current function and have jQuery send a request to the PHP file that handles it, and have the PHP file return the arrays for you. This will make it easier for your to deal with, and you won't have to always update the hardcode to set new products, or change details. Let me know, and I'll happily post up how you can do that with jQuery/AJAX/PHP.